# Spring MVC - Dispatcher Servlet can't find any page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I do really simple demo web app using `Spring mvc`, `Java class annotations` and `.jsp` instead of `.html`. 
When I start Tomcat on localhost - I always get 404 error. Where do I do mistake?

Config.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mylov.springsecurity.demo.config")
public class Config {

    //Define bean for ViewResolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Dispatcher Servlet Initialization

```
public class DispatcherServletInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{Config.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping({"", "/"})
    public String showHome() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: You do know that if you deploy to Tomcat - and you wont set otherwise - your application will be under autogenerated root context like `localhost/someappname/` and not `localhost/` right?

Comment: Yes, I do. I set up tomcat endpoint as "/"

Comment: When app starts, in logs on INFO level you have all mappings with coresponding controllers listed. Crosscheck your attempts with that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scan packages under **demo** package. So Spring will find your Controllers and Config classes. But now you point to only config. So package 'controller' won't be scan.

Try to do this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mylov.springsecurity.demo")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the mapping as below so that all url's are mapped with the servlet:

```
public class DispatcherServletInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{Config.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/*"};
    }
}
```

Also change the base packages to as below so that the controller class is also picked up for component scanning :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mylov.springsecurity.demo")
public class Config {
..........
}
```